Reputation Bonus?
Oggi ho aperto il sito, e mi sono trovato +100 di reputazione su ogni sito .SE a cui sono iscritto. 
 because we trust you on other sites in the network

Non mi lamento! Ma non me l'aspettavo assolutamente e mi chiedevo se fosse normale e quali fossero i criteri. 
In pratica è successo dopo che due mie risposte su Italian.SE hanno raggiunto 8 voti, ma questa è in realtà l'unica community dove riesco a dare un minimo di contributo.

I also have to mention that the questions could be in Italian or in English on the main site, but they must be only in English on Meta site. When you have time, please translate your question into English.

First of all, welcome to Italian SE and thanks for your contributions to the site.
The reputation changes are described here:

If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

Once your answers gained you 200+ reputation on Italian SE, your reputation was also raised on other SE sites to get you past the limitations for new users (such as restrictions for leaving comments, voting up and down, etc.).
